# Smudge / smear that is very hard to wash off

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the name (noun or adjective) for a smudge that is very difficult to wash off the surface?

**Example:**

> I tried to wash this ______ off my shirt, but it seems to be too ________ to remove

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can call it a *stubborn* stain.

> **stubborn** *adjective*
>   1.1 Difficult to move, remove, or cure.
>   ‘the removal of stubborn screws’
>   - [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stubborn)

Your example would then look like:

- I tried to wash this *stain* off my shirt, but it seems to be too *stubborn* to remove.

Comment: Amazing! Much obliged!

Answer (score 4):

I tried to wash this stain off my shirt, but it seems to be too stubborn to remove.

Answer (score 2):

***[Tough](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tough)*** is used referring to stains which are difficult to remove:

> very difficult to do or deal with. (M-W)

Usage examples:

From [Clean your house from A to Z](https://books.google.it/books?id=SmQvo2mnvgMC&q=%22tough%20stain%22&dq=%22tough%20stain%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9wMv9tYzZAhXIWxQKHcYPBR0Q6AEINDAE):

> ***Grass is a tough stain,*** one that is especially common on the knees of children's jeans.

From [Country living](https://books.google.it/books?id=j5byAAAAMAAJ&q=%22tough%20stain%22&dq=%22tough%20stain%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyoK3-t4zZAhVH0xQKHZuoBR0Q6AEISjAJ):

> TM OxyKIC combines an oxygen-activated cleaner with ***a tough stain fighter*** in one easy-to-use spray.

From [Clean it fast, clean it right](https://books.google.it/books?id=EIJXNyjx7bwC&pg=PA274&dq=%22tough%20stain%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr45XSuIzZAhUCWBQKHcjrAbcQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22tough%20stain%22&f=false):

> ***Oil is a tough stain***, plus it is like a magnet for dirt. Remove oil stains as quickly as possible.